# Widget TextView resize

Tags: android, android-widget, resize, textview

I have a widget that shows two TextView's shown here:

[image: widget screenshot]

What i want to know is, is it possible to resize the text when the widget is resized? Basically making the widget resizable as it should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the widget XML to fill parent and then enabling resizing.

For example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Flag your widget to be resizable with `android:resizeMode="vertical"` in your `<appwidget-provider ... />`

Now on newer Android versions, it will resize to fill as you resize the widget on your screen.

For lock screen widgets, setup you must do as bit more for the widget to be resizable. Take a gander at [App Widget sizing guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen-sizing)

Here is the relevant part

> When a widget is hosted on the lockscreen, the framework ignores the
>   minWidth, minHeight, minResizeWidth, and minResizeHeight fields. If a
>   widget is also a home screen widget, these parameters are still needed
>   as they're still used on home, but they will be ignored for purposes
>   of the lockscreen.
>
> The width of a lockscreen widget always fills the provided space. For
>   the height of a lockscreen widget, you have the following options:
>
> - If the widget does not mark itself as vertically resizable (android:resizeMode="vertical"), then the widget height will always be
>     "small":
>
>   - On a phone in portrait mode, "small" is defined as the space remaining when an unlock UI is being displayed.
>   - On tablets and landscape phones, "small" is set on a per-device basis.
> - If the widget marks itself as vertically resizable, then the widget height shows up as "small" on portrait phones displaying an unlock UI.
>     In all other cases, the widget sizes to fill the available height.

Comment: Thanks awesome answer but what im looking for is for when I resize the widget smaller for example it to change each TextView size. I don't know if this is possible though so thanks again for the great in depth answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Kirk's answer: If you draw the text on canvas (`Canvas.drawText(....)`), then the widget will resize the text automatically if you resize the widget. Unfortunately app widgets are only resizable from Android Honeycomb and upwards.